# Which one has red color in this phrase "the red bottle's lid"? the bottle or the lid?

Tags: grammar

Which one has red color in the following phrase?

> the red bottle's lid

the bottle or the lid?

### Edit

Now I understand the actual sentence with which I am faced.

> A more insidious attack strategy is to
>   coerce **an unwitting third-party
>   visitor’s browser** to send unwanted
>   HTTP requests on the attacker’s
>   behalf, abusing the identity
>   relationship already established
>   between your application and that
>   victim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The red bottle's lid

Normally it would be the bottle that was red. Because "red" stands before "bottle", and "bottle's lid" is not a single compound noun but two separate nouns, the ordinary pattern of `[adjective, noun it belongs to, anything else]` take precedence over the less frequent pattern `[adjective, noun that is the possessor of another noun, head noun to which the adjective belongs]`.

What kind of a lid do we have here? A *red bottle's* lid. Ah, but how do you know this lid comes off a red bottle? I see some glass splinters stuck to the lid.

Things change if you are using the first noun as a noun adjective, resulting in a compound noun:

> The red bottle lid

In this case, "bottle" is a noun adjective, not simply a regular noun with the possessive s; that makes "bottle lid" a single compound noun. Then "red" belongs to the entire compound noun; and because the final element of a compound noun ("lid") is the head (the "core" of the compound), the adjective mostly describes a property of the head. The lid is red.

What kind of red lid do we have here? A red *bottle* lid. Ah, right.

> The red lid of the bottle

Here "red" simply belongs to the first noun that follows it, because we have no compound noun, merely a prepositional attribute "of the bottle" and a head "lid".

What kind of a red lid do you have there? It is the red lid *of the bottle*! Huh, of what bottle? Oh, you know, of the bottle you got me drunk with yesterday, in order to have sex with you, which I would otherwise never have subjected myself to? Ah, right.

Answer (score 5):

> the red bottle's lid

means the **bottle** is red.

> the red bottle lid

means the **bottle lid** is red.

Answer (score 3):

- “The bottle's red lid” refer to the red lid of a particular bottle
- “The red bottle's lid” refers to the lid of a red bottle, which is indicated to be uniquely identifiable by its colour (i.e., you can't say that if there is more than one red bottle)
- “The red bottle lid” refers to a red lid belonging to a bottle; it can also weakly imply that the lid is not currently attached to a particular bottle.

Answer (score 2):

The bottle has the red colour in that sentence

the colour of the lid is completely unknown

Answer (score 1):

the red bottle's lid = the bottle is red.

If a lid were red = the red bottle lid (or of course, the bottle's red lid if talking specifically about a specific bottle)